# are there any hotkeys to force-close any program in windows?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

you know some programs dont close when it's frozen no matter what and sometimes not even the task manager works. Are there any hotkeys that literally force-closes any window? I searched it on google but all i could find was that old task manager method.

Comment: Alt-F4 can be used to close most programs, but it is not a force-close, but will work in some cases where the close button does not work, so... its semi-force close? Alt-F4 basically means, force-close window. If that's the only window, the program should end. Does work on most games if they freeze.

Comment: That said, the task manager should be able to close any window. If that doesn't work, there are simply multiple processes for a given window, and you need to close all. Try your luck in the processes tab.

Comment: You can also create a new shortcut, calling the "taskkill.exe /f /fi "status eq not responding"" command line instruction (no double quotes), give it a key combo like Shift-Alt-F4, or something else, up to you, and pin it to your Task Bar for ease of access.

Comment: If task manger does not do it no hotkey will.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built in, default keyboard commands, or key shortcut combinations, in Windows that offer what you ask.

The options presented in the comments above are the closest you can get.

Comment: The answer ought to re-state what the comments have already mentioned, if that's what will work. Comments aren't for answers, that's what the answer space is for.